# Query not giving updated result after database update in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a server setup in node.js that uses mongoose. The problem i am having is that when i update a database as follows

```
Questions.update({id:questionID}, {$push: {answers: {answer:answer,answeredBy:username}}}, callback);
```

I see that the data has been added in MongoCompass but when i query it using

```
Questions.find({tags:interests},callback);
```

the updated data is not returned. But if i restart the server and again query, i receive the updated result.

And if i just save the data and query by using `.save` method and query, the database is updated.

So the problem has to be with my `.update` method right? I really cant find what i am doing wrong

my database is as follows

```
let mongoose =new  require('mongoose');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

//Define a schema
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let QuestionsSchema = new Schema({

    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    title: String,
    details: String,
    askedDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    tags: [{

        type: String

    }],
    askedBy: String,
    answers: [{

        answeredBy: String,
        answer: String,
        answeredDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}

    }]

});

let Questions = module.exports = mongoose.model('Questions', QuestionsSchema);

module.exports.addQuestion = function (newQuestion, callback) {
    //generating a new random id for each question
    newQuestion.id = uuidv4();
    newQuestion.save(callback);
};
module.exports.addAnswer = function (username,answer, questionID, callback) {
    Questions.update({id:questionID}, {$push: {answers: {answer:answer,answeredBy:username}}}, callback);
};

module.exports.getQuestions = function (interests, callback) {
Questions.find({tags:interests},callback);



};
```

The methods are called as follows

```
 Questions.getQuestions(user.tags[i], function (err, questions) {
            if (err) {
                let output = {
                    error: {
                        status: "fail",
                        name: err.name,
                        message: err.message,
                        text: err.toString()
                    }
                };
                let statusCode = err.status || 500;
                res.json(output);
                res.send();
            }
            else {
                questions.map((data) => {
                    if (!sentTags.includes(data.id)) {
                        jsonResponse.push(data);
                        sentTags.push(data.id);
                    }
                });

                if (i === user.tags.length - 1) {
                    res.send(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse)));

                }
            }
        });
```

and

```
Questions.addAnswer(user.username,req.body.answer, req.body.id, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                let output = {
                    error: {
                        status: "fail",
                        name: err.name,
                        message: err.message,
                        text: err.toString()
                    }
                };
                let statusCode = err.status || 500;
                res.status(statusCode).json(output);
                res.send();
            }
            else {
                res.json({status: "success", message: "Answer Added"});
                res.send();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your DB has field named by "id" ?? because mongoose generate "_id".

Comment: yeah i added it myself

Comment: what is its type?

Comment: the problem is happening when i call find for the second time. Meaning that if i call find once and update and then find again i dont get updated data. if i update first then only call find the result is update.

Comment: Sounds like the record is only not being returned if it's queried immediately after it was written.  Sounds like a case of eventual consistency.  Can you set the read concern or write concern in Mongoose?

Comment: id is string and has unique constraint

Comment: setting read and write concerns? what do you mean by that Cuga?

Comment: Can you post your whole function, doing all three operations?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: when and where you call the two functions `getQuestions` and `addAnswer`

Comment: both addAnswer and getQuestions are part of different API. so they only get called when their respective API gets called

Comment: i have added the call for the two functions Ashish

Comment: @PuskarShestha I don't think this is because of MongoDB's consistency model. My hunch is this was caused by node's callback model. That is, in one case `addAnswer` gets called before `getQuestions` (the right order), and in the other case it's the other way around (the stale data order). With node, you cannot guarantee the order of function calls unless you specifically call one function inside the other's callback.

Comment: @kevin thanks for the reply. I am not calling these two functions at the same time. These two methods are invoked by two seperate API calls. Each API has access to only one of these two methods not both of them at once

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB is eventually consistent, if the Question is saved and then immediately updated, it could be the case that the changes haven't been fully propagated yet.

In Mongoose, try specifying the read concern to 'primary' with this:

```
Questions.find({tags:interests}).read('p').exec(callback)
```

[How to specify read concerns in Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-read)

[MongoDB Read Concern documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/)

Depending on the use-case, you may also want to explore the write concerns:

[MongoDB Write Concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/)

Comment: i am actually updating old questions. The only issue i am having is that I get the same result i got in the first query in all subsequent queries. if i update the database for 15 times and query for 1st time i get the updated result but if i update even 1 time then and query i get the previous query's result